# Is Android 4.2.2 still the best platform to develop an android app on?

Tags: android, performance, development-environment, platform

2 years ago i developed an app on android 4.2.2. I was wondering if the statistics are still the same?

If I developed it on android 4.2.2 now would it still be the best option? Will it be the optimum to reach the most devices?

Or is there a newer version that is mastering the market?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html I personally would go with API 16 or 17 depending on your planned delivery date.

Comment: There is a fundamental misunderstanding in your question. First, you need to target the highest that is supported by the Google Play, and that's currently API Level 21 (at the time of this post). Then, and only then, you pick a minSDKVersion number to support the versions in between.

Comment: I still support **Froyo (API Level 8)**, to catch even that little 0.6% of the global Android market. I will support it until it goes under the 0.1%.

Comment: @DerGolem Old API version can (and surely does) mean an old phone with bad performance. It also should be taken into account depending on the application type.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue You can't force people having `an old phone with bad performance` to buy a new one...

Comment: @DerGolem Yes of course, that's why depending on what application you provide, you'll choose to target them or not. Useless to be API 8 compliant if your application can't run on them due to performance.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue: That's why I always look for **lightweight**, **optimized** solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It is recomended that you always look at the market share of the Android versions to choose your entry version.
In the link below you can see the stats

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

As for today, I would recommend you to support API 15 and above (up to 21). It represents almost 90% of all devices, and as it represents Android 4.0, you can alredy use some Material design elements and use Fragments as you wish.

Comment: I still support **Froyo (API Level 8)**, to catch even that little 0.6% of the global Android market. I will support it until it goes under the 0.1%.